# how can I compress files of less than 300mb using some application for windows10

Tags: 7-zip

I have a folder with many files but I only want to compress the smallest, that is less than 300mb,

I suppose there must be some application that includes command line or some alternative to be able to perform that action.

Comment: `7z.exe` together with a batch file to find the smallest file will work ...

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill please reopen... I am about to write a very simple and straightforward answer that does not involve batch scripting.

Comment: @LPChip Done...

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this the following.

Any program that can create an archive from Windows Explorer will do. 7-zip included, but even Windows archiver will work.

What I'd do is just sort the files on size first ascending, then select the top most file, scroll down to the last file that is below your threshold, hold shift and click that file to make your selection.

Right-click the selection and compress that to a zip file.